# React Redux Blank Application

Tags: reactjs, redux, subscribe

I am trying to learn Redux. I have build a simple React application.

My index.js file looks as such

```
1 import React from 'react'
2 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
3 import './index.css'
4 import App from './components/App'
5 import {store} from './redux/store/store'
6 import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'

7 const render = () => ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))

8 render()
9 registerServiceWorker()
```

when I try to subscribe to my store by changing line 8 to

```
store.subscribe(render)
```

My application just becomes blank. Nothing is rendered to the screen and I don't receive any error messages.

Why is this happening?

Comment: is anything being dispatched? `subscribe` doesn't get called on its own

Answer (score 0):

Probably not an answer to your question, but you might wanna take a look at `react-redux` package. This lets you wrap a `<Provider />` higher order component what binds the store to your `<App />` easily (instead of what you're trying on line #7, 8).

Fx,

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import './index.css'
import App from './components/App'
import { store } from './redux/store/store'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'

const render = () => ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'))

render()
registerServiceWorker()
```

More on this can be found [here](https://gkedge.gitbooks.io/redux-course-notes/21-Passing_the_Store_Down_with_Provider_from_React_Redux.html) and [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-passing-the-store-down-with-provider-from-react-redux).